# java,Arraylist,morse code

Tags: java, arraylist

I have task to code a morse code converter in java. I input words and it converts them to morse code.

I should not use `HashMap` or `HashSet`. I can use `ArrayList`. I wrote it but I have error. Can you help me, pls

**The Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 65, Size: 0
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:685)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:494)
    at com.company.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:25)
```

**The code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main{

    final static String[][] code = {
            {"A", ".-     "}, {"B", "-...   "}, {"C", "-.-.   "}, {"D", "-..    "},
            {"E", ".      "}, {"F", "..-.   "}, {"G", "--.    "}, {"H", "....   "},
            {"I", "..     "}, {"J", ".---   "}, {"K", "-.-    "}, {"L", ".-..   "},
            {"M", "--     "}, {"N", "-.     "}, {"O", "---    "}, {"P", ".--.   "},
            {"Q", "--.-   "}, {"R", ".-.    "}, {"S", "...    "}, {"T", "-      "},
            {"U", "..-    "}, {"V", "...-   "}, {"W", ".-   - "}, {"X", "-..-   "},
            {"Y", "-.--   "}, {"Z", "--..   "}, {"0", "-----  "}, {"1", ".----  "},
            {"2", "..---  "}, {"3", "...--  "}, {"4", "....-  "}, {"5", ".....  "},
            {"6", "-....  "}, {"7", "--...  "}, {"8", "---..  "}, {"9", "----.  "},
            {"'", ".----. "}, {":", "---... "}, {",", "--..-- "}, {"-", "-....- "},
            {"(", "-.--.- "}, {".", ".-.-.- "}, {"?", "..--.. "}, {";", "-.-.-. "},
            {"/", "-..-.  "}, {"-", "..--.- "}, {")", "---..  "}, {"=", "-...-  "},
            {"@", ".--.-. "}, {"\"", ".-..-."}, {"+", ".-.-.  "}, {" ", "/"}};
    final static List<String> ascii = new ArrayList<String>();
static {
    for (String[] pair : code){
        ascii.add(pair[0].charAt(0), pair[1].trim());
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        printMorse("   Hello     World!");
    }
    static void printMorse(String input) {
        System.out.printf("%s %n", input);

        input = input.trim().replaceAll("[ ]+", " ").toUpperCase();
        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            String s = ascii.get(c);
            if (s != null){
                System.out.printf("%s ", s);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: line 25 is.... ?

Comment: for (String[] pair : code){
        ascii.add(pair[0].charAt(0), pair[1].trim());
    }

Comment: That's because `pair[0].charAt(0)` is not a valid index for `ascii.add(index, value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to declare `ascii` as a `Map<Character, String>`, not a `List<String>`. It is like a dictionnary where the Character is the key and the String is the morse value

```
final static Map<Character, String> ascii = new HashMap<>();
static {
    for (String[] pair : code){
        ascii.put(pair[0].charAt(0), pair[1].trim());
    }
}
```

After changing that, your code runs and outputs

```
   Hello     World! 
.... . .-.. .-.. --- / .-   - --- .-. .-.. -..
```

**EDIT:** Without a Map

If you won't want a `Map` you lose in efficiency, but it can be written this way, you don't need the `ascii` List. 
For each character, loop through your `code` Array and find the pair

```
final static String[][] code = {...}

public static void main(String[] args){
    printMorse("   Hello     World!");
}

static void printMorse(String input) {
    System.out.printf("%s %n", input);

    input = input.trim().replaceAll("[ ]+", " ").toUpperCase();

    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        // Find the pair for the character
        for(String[] pair : code) {
            if(pair[0].equals(String.valueOf(c))) {
                System.out.printf("%s ", pair[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Comment: but I should not use Map( How I can rewrite it using Arraylit?

Comment: @MadiyarKupzhassarov Why is that?

Comment: In task is written

Comment: @MadiyarKupzhassarov Please upvote and accept the answer if it solved your issue.